# Read multiple line as input in c# console application

Tags: c#, console

Input:
You should take input up to EOF. First line of each input will hold two numbers separated by a single space. First number will denote the total hours to finish the sprint (0 < CT ≤ 100) and the second one will be number of members in the team (0 < N ≤ 100). Then the N number of lines will hold the total hours a member can work each day (0 < P ≤ 24)

Output:
Print just single line for each test case. If it takes one day to finish the project then print “Project will finish within 1 day.” For more than one days print “Project will finish within D days.”, where D denotes the number of days to finish the project.

Sample Input
10 2
5
5
10 2
5
4
Sample Output
Project will finish within 1 day.
Project will finish within 2 days.

How can i solve this problem in c# console application?

I already create my method to calculate result, but it takes double enter to display result in console window

My Solution

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lines.Add(line);
}
getResult(lines);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imYTO.png)

Comment: Console.ReadLine() will return "" if only the enter key is pressed, it will not return null.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that you want to show the result when total members count is reached. So this is your improved code:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
string line;
int count = -2; // Current member index;
int totalcount = 0; // Total members count;
while (count < totalcount)
{
    line = Console.ReadLine();
    lines.Add(line);
    if(count == -1) // your app doesn't count first and second line
    {
        totalcount = Convert.ToInt32(line);
    }
    count++;
}
getResult(lines);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please check attach image in my question

Comment: @Mahady, please, tell me, what is wrong with my solution.

Comment: First: Your code read extra empty line. Second: It takes double enter press for display result (Execute getResult() method). Sir

Comment: @Mahady, you can use **while (count < totalcount - 1)** instead of **while (count < totalcount)**. So, this code won't take double enter press and don't read extra empty line.

Comment: Not working . Now getResult() method execute after first line not EOF

Comment: @Mahady, oops, I forgot that thing.  So, keep **while (count < totalcount - 1)**, but replace **int totalcount = 0** with **int totalcount = 1**

Comment: Line number is not fixed. I don't know how many lines are there.

Comment: Have you really tryed this code? I thought that **totalcount = Convert.ToInt32(line);** could help

Comment: Yes i tried , but when is change input then it not works.(It works fine with my given input above bot not other input). There is no way to know how many lines are there from input.

Comment: You said that the second line of console input tells how many members are there in the team. My code reads this line and repeats while statement certain times. What is the problem?

Comment: I never told 2nd line of console input tells how many members are there . Please see the attach image with my question. Sir